# What does a inner-product between a vector and matrix mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

I'm reading through Axler Sheldons *Linear Algebra Done Right*, and stumbled uppon the following question:

> Suppose $V$ is an inner-product space and $v,w \in \mathcal{L} (V)$. Define
>   $T  \in \mathcal{L} (V)$ by $Tu = \langle u,v \rangle w$. Find a formula for $trace (T)$.

The thing I can't wrap my head around is that $v$ is transformation (or matrix), and we're trying to take the inner product between a matrix and a vector.

If I assume that the $\mathcal{L}$ is nothing but a typo, then the whole statement makes sense, but I'm just wondering:

**Is the inner product between a vector and transform a valid operation?**

Comment: For me it seems a typo. Perhaps the intended condition is $v,w\in V$.

Comment: Axler has put erratas for his book online, classified by editions and printings. In particular, the last one here (http://linear.axler.net/LADRErrataSecondP12.html) seems to be exactly this exercise.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo is the second edition of my book Linear Algebra Done Right. The hypothesis should be that $v, w \in V$. This typo was fixed in the third edition of the book.